# How to upgrade kafka 0.7.2 to kafka 0.8?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am working on the `storm` and `kafka` for real time web analytics.

Currently i am using the following version it is working fine.

#### Note:

```
Storm - 0.9.0 
kafka - 0.7.2 
zookeeper - 3.3.3
```

I want to `upgrade` to `kafka 0.8 stable version`.

#### Problem:

Its hard to find out the dependencies for the latest version of kafka compatible with the storm.

Is there any working example for kafka 0.8 stable version with storm?

Any reference or suggestion will be grateful.

/**************************************************************************************************************************************/

1.I had tried this project https://github.com/wurstmeister/storm-kafka-0.8-plus-test with reference to the answer `Enno Shioji`

I am getting the following `error`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/topics/clickstreamlog/partitions
at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getBrokerInfo(DynamicBrokersReader.java:81) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at storm.kafka.trident.ZkBrokerReader.<init>(ZkBrokerReader.java:42) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.makeBrokerReader(KafkaUtils.java:57) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.open(KafkaSpout.java:87) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3284$fn__3299.invoke(executor.clj:520) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__452.invoke(util.clj:429) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [na:1.6.0_27]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/topics/clickstreamlog/partitions
at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getNumPartitions(DynamicBrokersReader.java:94) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getBrokerInfo(DynamicBrokersReader.java:65) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/topics/clickstreamlog/partitions
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:111) ~[zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5-1392090]
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51) ~[zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5-1392090]
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1586) ~[zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5-1392090]
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:214) ~[curator-framework-2.4.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:203) ~[curator-framework-2.4.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:107) ~[curator-client-2.4.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:199) ~[curator-framework-2.4.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:191) ~[curator-framework-2.4.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:38) ~[curator-framework-2.4.0.jar:na]
at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getNumPartitions(DynamicBrokersReader.java:91) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
... 8 common frames omitted
```

#### Topology

```
package storm;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import storm.kafka.BrokerHosts;
import storm.kafka.KafkaSpout;
import storm.kafka.SpoutConfig;
import storm.kafka.ZkHosts;
import backtype.storm.Config;
import backtype.storm.LocalCluster;
import backtype.storm.topology.BasicOutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import backtype.storm.topology.base.BaseBasicBolt;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Tuple;
import backtype.storm.utils.Utils;

public class TopologyMain {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,
        IOException {

    Config config = new Config();
    config.setDebug(true);

    TopologyBuilder topology = new TopologyBuilder();

    BrokerHosts hosts = new ZkHosts("127.0.0.1");
    SpoutConfig kafkaSpoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(hosts,"clickstreamlog", "127.0.0.1","discovery");

    KafkaSpout spout = new KafkaSpout(kafkaSpoutConfig);
    topology.setSpout("spout", spout,4);
    topology.setBolt("print", new PrinterBolt());

    LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
    cluster.submitTopology("Log", config, topology.createTopology());
    Utils.sleep(10000);
    cluster.killTopology("Log");
}

public static class PrinterBolt extends BaseBasicBolt {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {

    }

    public void execute(Tuple tuple, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
         System.out.println(tuple.toString());
    }

}
```

}

[Here](http://pastebin.com/6LXENPQH) pom.xml file.

2.I had tried this project https://github.com/eshioji/trident-tutorial as well.

`Note:` I am using the same topology code with different dependencies [pom.xml](https://github.com/eshioji/trident-tutorial/blob/master/pom.xml)

I am getting the following `error`

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:132) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:93) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor4.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeConstructor(Reflector.java:180) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.util$zip_contains_dir_QMARK_.invoke(util.clj:777) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$resources_jar$fn__5016.invoke(supervisor.clj:506) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at clojure.core$filter$fn__4226.invoke(core.clj:2533) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:67) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at clojure.lang.LazySeq.first(LazySeq.java:82) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at clojure.lang.RT.first(RT.java:577) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at clojure.core$first.invoke(core.clj:55) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$resources_jar.invoke(supervisor.clj:504) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$fn__5021.invoke(supervisor.clj:514) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:236) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$mk_synchronize_supervisor$this__4917.invoke(supervisor.clj:325) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.event$event_manager$fn__2379.invoke(event.clj:39) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [na:1.6.0_27]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is this one which uses docker:
https://github.com/wurstmeister/storm-kafka-0.8-plus-test

If you prefer Vagrant I have a repo that uses 0.9.2 & 0.8.x:
https://github.com/eshioji/trident-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is throwing error. I am using `TopologyBuilder` instead of `TridentTopology`. `java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file`

Comment: @karthick.k: You have to tell me which code you are running and what stacktrace you are getting...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I had edited my question noting that what i had tried with topology code and error.